# How can I check whether a syscall has been made from a signal handler?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I'm trying to make a syscall behave in a different way if it has been called from a signal handler, but I cannot find a way of checking this condition. Is there a flag in the current thread or task structure that I can check? TIF_SIGPENDING does not seem to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such flag now. TIF_SIGPENDING is a flag which marks signal pending, not signal being handled. The system is designed to works if signal handler never dismissed. The execution of syscall and signal handler is serialized.

One way is to backtrack user space call stack to search the signal frame for special magic number for the architecture, as pointed in arch/i386/kernel/signal.c - setup_frame():

```
/*
 * This is popl %eax ; movl $,%eax ; int $0x80
 *
 * WE DO NOT USE IT ANY MORE! It's only left here for historical
 * reasons and because gdb uses it as a signature to notice
 * signal handler stack frames.
 */
err |= __put_user(0xb858, (short __user *)(frame->retcode+0));
err |= __put_user(__NR_sigreturn, (int __user *)(frame->retcode+2));
err |= __put_user(0x80cd, (short __user *)(frame->retcode+6));
```

But since you are changing the kernel, why not just hack it? just manipulate a counter in handle_signal/sys_sigreturn/sys_rt_sigreturn. And you need to cover all the exceptions, such such signal handler never call sigreturn.